# Renaming Dictionary data string in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have this data structure:

```
{'scripting': {'grel': {'defaultExpression': 'value', 'name': 'Google Refine Expression Language (GREL)'}, 'clojure': {'defaultExpression': 'value', 'name': 'Clojure'}}, 'overlayModels': {}, 'recordModel': {'hasRecords': False}, 'columnModel': {'columnGroups': [], 'keyColumnName': 'Afiles - segments - ASegment - seg', 'columns': [{'originalName': 'Afiles - segments - ASegment - seg', 'cellIndex': 10, 'name': 'Afiles - segments - ASegment - seg'}, {'originalName': 'Afiles - segments - ASegment - Conf', 'cellIndex': 15, 'name': 'Afiles - segments - ASegment - Conf'}, {'originalName': 'Afiles - segments - ASegment - alaw', 'cellIndex': 13, 'name': 'Afiles - segments - ASegment - alaw'}, {'originalName': 'Afiles - segments - ASegment - trim', 'cellIndex': 12, 'name': 'Afiles - segments - ASegment - trim'}, {'originalName': 'Afiles - segments - ASegment - sname', 'cellIndex': 11, 'name': 'Afiles - segments - ASegment - sname'}, {'originalName': 'Afiles - segments - ASegment - recog', 'cellIndex': 14, 'name': 'Afiles - segments - ASegment - recog'}, {'originalName': 'Afiles - segments - ASegment - Results', 'cellIndex': 8, 'name': 'Afiles - segments - ASegment - Results'}, {'originalName': 'Afiles - segments - ASegment - Literal', 'cellIndex': 9, 'name': 'Afiles - segments - ASegment - Literal'}, {'originalName': 'Afiles - amp', 'cellIndex': 2, 'name': 'Afiles - amp'}, {'originalName': 'Afiles - errors', 'cellIndex': 7, 'name': 'Afiles - errors'}, {'originalName': 'Afiles - mishit', 'cellIndex': 5, 'name': 'Afiles - mishit'}, {'originalName': 'Afiles - matches', 'cellIndex': 3, 'name': 'Afiles - matches'}, {'originalName': 'Afiles - nomatch', 'cellIndex': 6, 'name': 'Afiles - nomatch'}, {'originalName': 'Afiles - silence', 'cellIndex': 1, 'name': 'Afiles - silence'}, {'originalName': 'Afiles - filename', 'cellIndex': 0, 'name': 'Afiles - filename'}, {'originalName': 'Afiles - matchesAboveThreshold', 'cellIndex': 4, 'name': 'Afiles - matchesAboveThreshold'}], 'keyCellIndex': 0}}
```

I would like to replace values for `originalName` and `name` with the last element in the string (after the last hyphen).

e.g. 'Afiles - segments - ASegment - seg' becomes 'seg'
Required output:

```
{'scripting': {'grel': {'defaultExpression': 'value', 'name': 'Google Refine Expression Language (GREL)'}, 'clojure': {'defaultExpression': 'value', 'name': 'Clojure'}}, 'overlayModels': {}, 'recordModel': {'hasRecords': False}, 'columnModel': {'columnGroups': [], 'keyColumnName': 'Afiles - segments - ASegment - seg', 'columns': [{'originalName': 'seg', 'cellIndex': 10, 'name': 'seg'}, {'originalName': 'Conf', 'cellIndex': 15, 'name': 'Conf'}, {'originalName': 'alaw', 'cellIndex': 13, 'name': 'alaw'}, {'originalName': 'trim', 'cellIndex': 12, 'name': 'trim'}, {'originalName': 'sname', 'cellIndex': 11, 'name': 'sname'}, {'originalName': ' recog', 'cellIndex': 14, 'name': ' recog'}, {'originalName': 'Results', 'cellIndex': 8, 'name': ' Results'}, {'originalName': ' Literal', 'cellIndex': 9, 'name': ' Literal'}, {'originalName': ' amp', 'cellIndex': 2, 'name': ' amp'}, {'originalName': ' errors', 'cellIndex': 7, 'name': ' errors'}, {'originalName': ' mishit', 'cellIndex': 5, 'name': ' mishit'}, {'originalName': ' matches', 'cellIndex': 3, 'name': ' matches'}, {'originalName': ' nomatch', 'cellIndex': 6, 'name': ' nomatch'}, {'originalName': ' silence', 'cellIndex': 1, 'name': ' silence'}, {'originalName': ' filename', 'cellIndex': 0, 'name': ' filename'}, {'originalName': ' matchesAboveThreshold', 'cellIndex': 4, 'name': ' matchesAboveThreshold'}], 'keyCellIndex': 0}}
```

Comment: it is not json data. It is an ordinary dict.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `q_dict` is the above data, this is what you are looking for:

```
result = [item['name'].split('-')[-1].strip() for item in q_dict['columnModel']['columns']]
```

Explanation: The type of your data is a dictionary. The item of your interest is the list that can be obtained by `q_dict['columnModel']['columns']`.

Each item in this list is a dictionary. You want to get the last segment of the string in this dictionary whose key is `name`. `item['name']` gets you that.

Now we split the string using `-` as the key and get the last element in this split list by doing `item['name'].split('-')[-1]`

The `strip()` gets rid of the whitespaces around your result.

**EDIT:**

To replace the data in place, here is what you do:

```
a_list = q_dict['columnModel']['columns']
new_list = []
for item in a_list:
    temp_dict = {}
    for k, v in item.items():
        if k == 'name' or k == 'originalName':
            temp_dict[k] = v.split('-')[-1].strip()
        else:
            temp_dict[k] = v
    new_list.append(temp_dict)
q_dict['columnModel']['columns'] = new_list
```

Comment: i want to rename it to the same q_dict

Comment: this is way too complicated - check out my answer

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are asking then a simple loop will achieve this.

I have separated out the transform function in case you want to tweak it.

```
def transform(original):
    return original.split('-')[-1].strip()

for col in data['columnModel']['columns']:
    col['name'] = transform(col['originalName'])
    del col['originalName'] #if you want to remove the original
    #col['originalName'] = transform(col['originalName']) #if you want to keep both
print data['columnModel']['columns']
```

The result, all neat:

> [{'cellIndex': 10, 'name': 'seg'}, {'cellIndex': 15, 'name': 'Conf'},
>   {'cellIndex': 13, 'name': 'alaw'}, {'cellIndex': 12, 'name': 'trim'},
>   {'cellIndex': 11, 'name': 'sname'}, {'cellIndex': 14, 'name':
>   'recog'}, {'cellIndex': 8, 'name': 'Results'}, {'cellIndex': 9,
>   'name': 'Literal'}, {'cellIndex': 2, 'name': 'amp'}, {'cellIndex': 7,
>   'name': 'errors'}, {'cellIndex': 5, 'name': 'mishit'}, {'cellIndex':
>   3, 'name': 'matches'}, {'cellIndex': 6, 'name': 'nomatch'},
>   {'cellIndex': 1, 'name': 'silence'}, {'cellIndex': 0, 'name':
>   'filename'}, {'cellIndex': 4, 'name': 'matchesAboveThreshold'}]